# Can't install pandas-dedupe on Windows Python 3.9

Tags: python, pandas, pip, duplicates, levenshtein-distance

Running `pip install pandas-dedupe`, I get the following error:
[image]

I tried manually installing python-Levenshtein first and got the same problem with the addition [image]. What can I do?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5586359 Text, please! http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode. [edit] your question, copy/paste from the terminal and properly [format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) it as code. Images are not helpful, they're hard to read and hard to search. Badly formatted code is hard to read. Images are only good to show something non-textual (like colors, fonts, screen positions, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/.
In the installation guide, choose "Desktop development with C++".